# R: Error in optim (curve-fitting)

Tags: r, excel, curve-fitting

I am trying to figure out the parameters for attack rate `a` and handling time `h` to be used in producing a maximum likelihood for my data set of consumed prey densities.

I am using the `frair` package on R for this task, and the following function:

```
Rogersfit<-frair_fit(eaten~density, data=bob, response='rogersII', start=list(a=x, h=y), fixed=list(T=24))
```

However, this requires that I enter random values for `a` and `h` manually, which takes a considerable amount of time. If the entered values are not correct, it returns the Error message:

> Error in frfunc(data = moddata, samp = c(1:nrow(moddata)), start = start,  : 
>    Error in optim(par = structure(c(1, 0), .Names = c("a", "h")), fn = function (p)  :
>    function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

In order to eliminate the guess-work involved in finding the initial parameter values, I created an excel sheet with 2 columns of values that R would run through:

```
# a h #

# 1 0.01 #

# 1 0.02 #

# 1 0.03 #

# . . #

# . . #

# . . #

# 9 0.98 #

# 9 0.99 #
```

And used the following code to input the values:

```
x <- as.numeric(as.character(test$a))

y <- as.numeric(as.character(test$h))


for (i in 1:900){

  for (j in 1:900){

    Rogersfit<-frair_fit(eaten~density, data=bob, response='rogersII', start=list(a=x[i], h=y[j]), fixed=list(T=24))

 }

 }
```

I have assigned the variable `x` to the first column of my excel sheet, which represents the attack rate. The variable `y` has been assigned to the second column representing the handling time.

The objective is to input these values into the function until it returns the true parameters according to the maximum likelihood fit, but the above code gives the same error message and stops at the first set of values (1, 0.01) in the excel sheet.

I was thinking of working with a boolean operator, such as if `response == error` go to next row of values, but I don't know if this is possible with R as I have only just begun using this language.

Comment: Just as a quick comment, I'm not sure if "producing maximum likelihood" is the correct phrasing here. On a more important note, could you provide a brief sample dataset with which we play play around? Also, the list over which you are iterating is not quite clear. If my interpretation is correct then you should try this: `grid = expand.grid(seq(1,9, by=1), seq(0,1, by=.01))` and then iterate over `start=list(a=grid[i], h=[i])` but that's quite exhaustive and are you sure that the parameter values are in that range?

Comment: I meant "maximum likelihood fit/estimation", sorry about that.

The parameter values should be somewhere in that range. If not, the data sheet can be modified to a larger range.

Would you like the excel file to get an idea of the data set?